# Access parent class variables from child class variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
class Duck:
  SIZE = 'Fat'

class GreenDuck(Duck):
  COLOR = 'Green'
  DESCRIPTION = SIZE + ' and '  + COLOR

>>> alien_duck = GreenDuck()
>>> print(alien_duck.DESCRIPTION)

NameError: name 'SIZE' is not defined 

>>> alien_duck.SIZE
Fat
```

Is there a way I can access the parent 'size' class variable from inside the class?

Also defining `super().__init__()` in the GreenDuck class doesn't fix it.

Comment: The question is inaccurate. You're trying to access base class variables from a derived class. It would be a child class if GreenDuck was nested as a member class inside Duck

Answer (score 4):

Since it's a class constant:

```
class GreenDuck(Duck):
    COLOR = 'Green'
    DESCRIPTION = Duck.SIZE + ' and '  + COLOR
```

Comment: But what if I want to define a new size for my green ducks? Then I'd have to change `Duck.SIZE` to just `SIZE`? Will defining it in lowercase make it work with just `SIZE`

Answer (score 1):

When accessing variables from another class , class.variableName should be used instead of just variable name .

If you want to access variables within the same class (which is also present in the parent class )  , self.variableName can be used to refer to the variables defined in the scope of the current class .